# Yaml ">" is joining multiple lines as multiple strings instead of a single string in AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have this in my cloudformation template:

```
  FargateTaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      Cpu: 512
      ExecutionRoleArn: !Ref ECSTaskExecutionRole
      Memory: 2048
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      RequiresCompatibilities:
        - FARGATE
      TaskRoleArn: !Ref ECSTaskExecutionRole
      ContainerDefinitions:
        -
          Name: "dlt-fargate-task"
          Essential: true
          Image: some/image
          Memory: 500
          LogConfiguration:
            LogDriver: awslogs
            Options:
              awslogs-group: !Ref FargateTaskCloudWatchLogGroup
              awslogs-region: us-east-1
              awslogs-stream-prefix: "dlt-fargate"
          EntryPoint:
            - "/bin/bash"
            - "-c"
          Command:
            - >
              '/bin/bash -c echo ''blah'' > file1.json;
              cat file1.json;
              echo lsdkfjlsdfjsdfj;
              ...do more stuff
```

If I throw everything for command on the same line like this it works:

```
      Command:
        - 'bin/bash -c command1 -balh; command2 blah; etc
```

But I think the folding yaml function is doing something weird because it looks like its trying to run it as a single command or something

I think this is the problem:
[image]

My task definitions reflects this too:

In my task def I want to see this when using "<"

```
["echo aaaaa && echo bbbbbb && echo ccccccc"]
```

But instead the task def shows this

```
["'echo aaaaa && ' 'echo bbbbbb && ' 'echo ccccccc'\n"]
```

### Edit

I can't believe I didn't see this; I should not have wrapped the lines in quotes. This works as expected, I just needed to not wrap multi-lines in quotes.

Comment: https://yaml-multiline.info/

Comment: `>` is not joining strings correctly it seems

Answer (score 0):

`Command` is an array, so you can put multiple commands in it:

```
          Command:
            - '/bin/bash -c echo ''blah'' > file1.json;
            - cat file1.json;
            - echo lsdkfjlsdfjsdfj;
            - ...do more stuff
```

Comment: how does ecs execute them? do I still need to end with ";" or does it just execute multiple commands? I tried just defining multiple commands like that and it only ran the first one